How to hide "Create theme with AI" in Google Chrome?
How to hide or disable the "Create theme with AI" button in Google Chrome? It's distracting.
200+ people have the same question at https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/274716224/how-can-i-delete-the-create-theme-with-ai-tool-bar-on-my-computer-screen?hl=en

Create a file disable-chrome-ai-theme.reg with the following content:
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome]
"CreateThemesSettings"=dword:00000002

And run it.
Thanks to https://chromeenterprise.google/intl/en_uk/policies/#CreateThemesSettings
